DevOps CD Pipeline Error Mutliple dacpac records
I hope you can help as I can't seem to find a structured scenario to fix the problem.

2024-08-22T15:44:19.1135863Z ##[section]Starting: SQL DB Deploy
2024-08-22T15:44:19.1143548Z
============================================================================== 2024-08-22T15:44:19.1143696Z Task         : SQL Server database deploy
2024-08-22T15:44:19.1143761Z Description  : Deploy a SQL Server
database using DACPAC or SQL scripts 2024-08-22T15:44:19.1143875Z
Version      : 0.198.0 2024-08-22T15:44:19.1143935Z Author       :
Microsoft Corporation 2024-08-22T15:44:19.1144005Z Help         :
https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group
2024-08-22T15:44:19.1144147Z
============================================================================== 2024-08-22T15:44:21.1487666Z ##[error]Found more than one file to
deploy with search pattern C:\azagent\A3_work\r2\a***.dacpac. There
can be only one. 2024-08-22T15:44:21.1857827Z ##[section]Finishing:
SQL DB Deploy

It's true, there are two dacpac's in this directory. I don't know how there are two, one is called Master.dacpac. I am picking up where someone left off, and they are not around. My knowledge is limited. As in I can get it to work when there are no problems. When I hit a problem, I can never find the solution. I'm sure someone must have already hit this issue.
I'm thinking that removing the file that I don't want and then rerunning the CI part that creates the dacpac, to make sure that the master doesn't reappear. If it doesn't 'happy daze'.
I just don't know where this drop directory is located? You can navigate to it to see that there are two files. But I can't seem to find a way to locate where this directory is to remove the file. It's on Azure DevOps so is there a tool that can help you navigate? An Azure Explorer, if you like?
Any help would be gratefully received.

It would help to see more details, for example the pipeline definition.

As per the error message:
##[error]Found more than one file to deploy with search pattern C:\azagent\A3_work\r2\a***.dacpac. There can be only one.

You are using self-hosted DevOps agent, and it will find more than one dacpac with pattern C:\azagent\A3_work\r2\a***.dacpac, then the error occurs.
** is recursive wildcard, it will find all match files, please check the Pattern syntax for the usage detail.
Also, as per the location structure C:\azagent\A3_work\r2\a***.dacpac, the dacpac should come from pipeline artifact which is created from another build pipeline.
To resolve the issue, you can delete the other dacpac files not needed from pipeline artifact(you need to rebuild the artifact from build pipeline to achieve), but better way is, you can specify more accurate name in the pattern so that it will only match one dacpac.
For example, in classic UI pipeline, you can click the button, navigate to target folder, choose the target dacpac.

In yaml pipeline, you can specify the exact dacpac file name, sample below：
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Deploy someDb_DB'
  inputs:
    DacpacFile: '**/abc.dacpac'   # <-- abc.dacpac is the exact dacpac name
    ServerName: '(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB'
    DatabaseName: db


It's amazing what a sleep can do.
So, where is the file I want to delete?
It's not in the cloud, in devOps somewhere, it is on the local machine. However, when I say 'local', it is the machine that has SQL Server on it, the one that you are trying to install/update your database using CD.
So if you search for this on 'that' machine, you will find what you are looking for.
Next step is to see why the CI is creating 2 files. But I now know that due to the timestamp that it is being produced at the same time.
Thanks all for looking.

Pipelines are running on the agent(the local machine you used to deploy), and code will be checked out to the agent, if you delete the file on the local agent, it will checkout again if you run the pipeline again. Can you confirm if it's resolved? Thanks

@wadezhou-MSFT I have two CI pipelines on two different databases and each pipeline looks exactly the same except for the repo and database, however the pipeline in question is returning 2 dacpac files, where as the other is only building one, Master and Warehouse. So it is the CI where the issue is. What should I be looking at to solve this build? I can't see why there is only one branch in the GIT, called Master. The files are of different sizes. When I try to build a new DB with the artifact the release fails. But no error code.

The dacpac files could come from: 1. your soucre repo 2. generated by your pipeline tasks. Without your detail pipeline definition, it's hard to say where the dacpac comes from. Please show the pipeline definition, and source repo structure. But as i stated below, the best way is to pick target dacpac for pipeline, whatever how many dacpac you have, it will work.
